# Get the accuracy of individual test images in image segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network

I am using CNNs in Tensorflow for image segmentation.I know how to compute the training accuracy

```
 #compute the accuracy
    correct_prediction  = tf.equal(tf.argmax(flat_logits, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))



[train_accuracy] = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y:batch_y})
```

is it possible to compute the accuracy of the accuracy of each individual tested images?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can do it by simply writing:

```
test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y:y_test})
```

where x_test is your single test image (say of size [1, width, height, depth] and y_test is the corresponding output.